# error while installing binutils in LFS

Tags: linux

lfs:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build$ ../binutils-2.15.94.0.2.2/configure \

> --target=$LFS_TGT --prefix=/tools \
>   --disable-nls --disable-werror
>   loading cache ./config.cache
>   checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnuoldld
>   checking target system type... i686-lfs-linux-gnu
>   checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnuoldld
>   checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether ln works... yes
>   checking whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking for gcc... no
>   checking for cc... no
>   configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if gcc and build-essential are installed on your system. If that is not the problem, then check this link
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=711835